# Ignore certain Entity fields in Controller level

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following JPA entity

```
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;

    private LocalDate start_date;
    private LocalDate end_date;
    private String tag;
    private String status;
```

let's say I want to send a GET request where I get only the name,description and status while ignoring the other fields. how can i achieve that?

I want to ignore certain fields ONLY FOR THIS SPECIFIC REQUEST, so using @JSONIGNORE is out of the question

Comment: You can look into spring projections. This will help you.

Comment: You could create another class, a "sparse" DTO that includes only those important fields. Rather than returning Task, the endpoint would return the new class.

Comment: @mahesh that's what i'm currently doing with it but it seems unpractical. is there a better alternative?